# How do I get rid of Azure Powershell warning "WARNING: AzureVM A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming..."

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have some old Azure Powershell scripts that I'm breaking out of mothballs to use again.  They seem to work as I remember them, except I'm getting these warnings:

> $VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $nic.Id
>
> WARNING: Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface: A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming breaking change release. The Name property
> for a Sku will return Standard_LRS and Premium_LRS
>
> $vm = Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -VM $VirtualMachine -Disable
>
> WARNING: Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics: A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming breaking change release. The
> StorageAccountType property for a DataDisk will return Standard_LRS
> and Premium_LRS

I'm not using any of the output in my scripts so the warnings are useless.  There's a lot of output in these scripts and I only want to see stuff that really concerns the health of the script and the objects created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the breaking change warning with the following environment variable:

`Set-Item Env:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"`

More information here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/documentation/breaking-changes/breaking-changes-messages-help.md

Comment: This stopped working for me (using the env var to suppress)

Answer (score 4):

In early 2023, Microsoft changed things again. Now, the https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings docs say to use:

```
Update-AzConfig -DisplayBreakingChangeWarning $false

# Or use this to avoid pushing the result into PS's output pipeline
[void](Update-AzConfig -DisplayBreakingChangeWarning $false)
```

Those docs still link to [another page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/documentation/breaking-changes/breaking-changes-attribute-help.md#suppress-the-breaking-change-messages-at-runtime) that says you can use an environment variable as an alternative:

```
Set-Item Env:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"
```

However, that environment variable stopped working for me.

Comment: Just to add a bit more to the new method you can scope this to the "process" so you're not perma-disabling it for the system or opening the door to issues by calling it multiple times from different processes. `Update-AzConfig -Scope Process -DisplayBreakingChangeWarning $false | Out-Null`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can use '-WarningAction 0' parameter in your command to supress warning messages. Hope this helps!